# How to calculate the number of customers' flow in different periods by loop in R

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
A <- data.table("ID"=c(001, 002, 003, 004, 005), 
                "DATE"=c(200808, 200808, 200808, 200808, 200808))
B <- data.table("ID"=c(001, 002, 003, 005), 
                "DATE"=c(200809, 200809, 200809, 200809))
C <- data.table("ID"=c(001, 002, 003, 005, 006), 
                "DATE"=c(200810, 200810, 200810, 200810, 200810))
D <- data.table("ID"=c(001, 002, 003, 005, 006, 007), 
                "DATE"=c(200811, 200811, 200811, 200811, 200811, 200811))
E <- data.table("ID"=c(001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006), 
                "DATE"=c(200812, 200812, 200812, 200812, 200812, 200812))
RAW <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all.x= T , all.y = T, all=T), 
              list(A, B, C, D, E))
> RAW
    ID   DATE
 1:  1 200808
 2:  1 200809
 3:  1 200810
 4:  1 200811
 5:  1 200812
 6:  2 200808
 7:  2 200809
 8:  2 200810
 9:  2 200811
10:  2 200812
11:  3 200808
12:  3 200809
13:  3 200810
14:  3 200811
15:  3 200812
16:  4 200808
17:  4 200812
18:  5 200808
19:  5 200809
20:  5 200810
21:  5 200811
22:  5 200812
23:  6 200810
24:  6 200811
25:  6 200812
26:  7 200811
    ID   DATE
```

I need to calculate the number of customers' flow in different periods by loop in R.
And I have an idea, is to separate the "Raw" by "ID" and "DATE", and merge them again like this.

```
Data <- RAW[RAW$DATE==200808, c("ID", "DATE")]; colnames(Data)[2] <- 200808
for(i in 200809:200812){
  next_month <- RAW[RAW$DATE==i, c("ID", "DATE")]
  colnames(next_month)[2] <- i
  Data <- merge(Data, next_month, by = "ID", 
                all.x= T , all.y = T, all=T)}
> Data
   ID 200808 200809 200810 200811 200812
1:  1 200808 200809 200810 200811 200812
2:  2 200808 200809 200810 200811 200812
3:  3 200808 200809 200810 200811 200812
4:  4 200808     NA     NA     NA 200812
5:  5 200808 200809 200810 200811 200812
6:  6     NA     NA 200810 200811 200812
7:  7     NA     NA     NA 200811     NA
```

So I can figure out the increase and decrease of population and the net population.
And put the output into "Dynamic".

```
Dynamic <- data.frame("Year"=c(200808:200812), "beginning"=c(0))
Dynamic <- cbind(Dynamic, plus=rep(0,nrow(Dynamic)), minus=rep(0,nrow(Dynamic)), 
                 net=rep(0,nrow(Dynamic)), end=rep(0,nrow(Dynamic)))
colnames(Dynamic) <- c("year", "beginning", "plus", "minus", "net", "end")
> Dynamic
    year beginning plus minus net end
1 200808         0    0     0   0   0
2 200809         0    0     0   0   0
3 200810         0    0     0   0   0
4 200811         0    0     0   0   0
5 200812         0    0     0   0   0
```

And for example (200808 to 200809), the process will be like,

```
Data <- RAW[RAW$DATE==200808, c("ID", "DATE")]; colnames(Data)[2] <- 200808

for(i in 200809:200812){
  next_month <- RAW[RAW$DATE==i, c("ID", "DATE")]
  colnames(next_month)[2] <- i
  Data <- merge(Data, next_month, by = "ID", 
                all.x= T , all.y = T, all=T)}

for(z in 2:5){ # for the dynamic's date
  for(j in 1:7){ # Data tab
    if(is.na(Data[j, 2])==F&is.na(Data[j, 3])==F){next} # two col both have data
    if(is.na(Data[j, 2])==F&is.na(Data[j, 3])==T){ # col 2 have，col 3 don't have
      if((Data[j, 2]+1)==Dynamic[z, 1]){ # match the date +1 is beacuse col3 is NA
        Dynamic[z, 4] <- Dynamic[z, 4] + 1  # + 1
      }else{next}} # means have one person gone
    if(is.na(Data[j, 2])==T&is.na(Data[j, 3])==F){ #col 2 don't have，col 3 have
      if(Data[j, 3]==Dynamic[z, 1]){ # match the date
        Dynamic[z, 3] <- Dynamic[z, 3] + 1 # + 1
      }} # means have new guys come in 
    if(is.na(Data[j, 2])==T&is.na(Data[j, 3])==T){next}}} # both don't have data
> Dynamic
    year beginning plus minus net end
1 200808         0    0     0   0   0
2 200809         0    0     1   0   0
3 200810         0    0     0   0   0
4 200811         0    0     0   0   0
5 200812         0    0     0   0   0
```

And we can see, in 200809 have one guy is gone.
But when I try to merge all the code together, so that I can put all timing's(Date) output to "Dynamic".
It doesn't work.

```
for(z in 2:5){
  for(j in 1:7){
    for(i in 200809:200812){
      next_month <- RAW[RAW$DATE==i, c("ID", "DATE")] 
      colnames(next_month)[2] <- i # 
      Data <- merge(Data, next_month, by = "ID", 
                    all.x= T , all.y = T, all=T)

      if(is.na(Data[j, 2])==F&is.na(Data[j, 3])==F){next} # two col both have data
      if(is.na(Data[j, 2])==F&is.na(Data[j, 3])==T){ # col 2 have，col 3 don't have
        if((Data[j, 2]+1)==Dynamic[z, 1]){ # match the date
          Dynamic[z, 4] <- Dynamic[z, 4] + 1  # + 1
          }else{next}} # 少了人
      if(is.na(Data[j, 2])==T&is.na(Data[j, 3])==F){ # col 2 don't have，col 3 have
        if(Data[j, 3]==Dynamic[z, 1]){ # match the date
          Dynamic[z, 3] <- Dynamic[z, 3] + 1 # + 1
        }} # means have new guys come in 
      if(is.na(Data[j, 2])==T&is.na(Data[j, 3])==T){next}
      
      Data <- Data[ , -2]}}}


Error in merge.data.table(Data, next_month, by = "ID", all.x = T, all.y = T,  : 
  x has some duplicated column name(s): 200809.x,200809.y. Please remove or rename the duplicate(s) and try again.
In addition: Warning message:
In merge.data.table(Data, next_month, by = "ID", all.x = T, all.y = T,  :
  column names '200809.x', '200809.y' are duplicated in the result
```

By the way, I try to delete the col 2 at the end is because, I need to use the code in big data, I have to delete the col 2 at he end, and in next loop can merge a new timing to compare again.
Can someone help me, thanks!

Comment: This is an extremely complicated question and it is very difficult to follow what you are trying to acheive. First you introduce some data and then jump to various conclusions about how it should be done, which obviously do not work, since you are posting your question here.  You need to include some examples of what the output would look like, for a single ID, year or date, i.e. what is a "flow"?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my eloquence is not good. First, we can see some missing values from "Data ID", and then there may be a date in the next year, which means that he is a newcomer. I want to calculate between one year and come in. And the number of people who left. And I can put the result into "Dynamic".